# ie8 postback fiddler

Tags: asp.net, forms, internet-explorer-8, postback, fiddler

The search form on my site behave wrong on IE (I've tried IE8 & IE7)
When I click On a linkButton, or checkBoxes, that launches a postback and all fields are reset. All previously found results are reset too, the page becomes empty as if loaded for the first time.

This doesn't happens on FF nor Chrome.

If I run Fiddler to see what's going on, the page works perfectly well and the postback returns me all my datas. I guess Fiddler corrects it so I can't see what's wrong with the query IE send to the server.

Now, let's see the code.
First things first, the HTML page calling the .Net content :

```
<iframe width="605" scrolling="AUTO" height="6000" frameborder="NO" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://[MYSERVERNAME]/xml/dialog/rechercher.aspx?L=FR" id="iframe_"></iframe>
```

Then, the ASPX page file "rechercher.aspx" :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/xml/Dialog/rechercher.aspx.cs" Inherits="xml_Dialog_rechercher" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Recherche</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
    <!-- other js calls -->
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('/lib_central/images/ACTIV/common/bgd_main.gif');background-repeat:repeat-y;">

    <form runat="server">

        <!--
            some presentation code
            ...
        -->

        <!-- sample of one of the search fields -->
        <label for="motsClefs" class="bold"><% Response.Write(get_label("motcle")); %></label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="rech_kw" runat="server" value="" ForeColor="#999999" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>

        <!-- The validation field -->
        <asp:LinkButton ID="rech_valide" OnClick="lancer_recherche" runat="server" CssClass="boutons rechercher inlineBlk" >
        <span class="rechercher"><span class="alt_text">rechercher</span></span></asp:LinkButton>
        <br class="clear" />

        <%-- Results displaying --%>
        <div ID="resultats" class="contentDia alignementBlk" runat="server"></div>


        <!--
            some footer code
            ...
        -->

        <!-- Tell the parent page to stretch according to the number of results -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#iframe_666', window.parent.document).height(100+$(".contentDialogue").height());
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the .Net code behind :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UsersData;

public partial class xml_Dialog_rechercher : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string keyword = ""; // Champ de saisie texte
    List<DLG_Questions> list_q;
    public string lang;


    // Au chargement de la page
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    // If the form validation button is clicked
    protected void lancer_recherche(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If user typed something in search field
        if (get_filters())
        {
            // Query the data layer to retrieve what is searched
            this.list_q = DialogManager.recherche(this.keyword);

            // Display resultst
            if (this.list_q.Count == 0)
            {
                resultats.InnerHtml = "no results";
            }
            else
            {
                resultats.InnerHtml = display_question_list();
            }
        }
    }



    // "Read" input field controls.
    // If all empty => return FALSE
    // if some contains data => Save that data and return TRUE
    protected bool get_filters()
    {
        // ...

        return ret;
    }


    // Return a HTML of the list of themes searched
    public string display_question_list(){
        // ...
    }


    // Internationnalisation allow me to display labels in different languages
    protected string get_label(String cle)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```